# parse JSON withi UTF-8 Value in delphi xe3 with TlkJSONobject

Tags: json, parsing, delphi, utf-8, delphi-xe3

I wanna parse JSON than have UTF-8 string but when I show this value in delphi XE3 in a label just show ???? but when show in ShowMessage(); this value is correct please help me
value: 'سعید'

my code:

```
procedure TServerMethods1.Ins_Info(var TehResult: String);
var    
    name: string;
    js,xs:TlkJSONobject;
begin
    js := TlkJSON.ParseText(ThResult) as TlkJSONobject;
    if not assigned(js) then
    begin
        readln;
        exit;
   end
   else
   begin
      name := AnsiToUtf8(js.getString('name'));
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Surely TlkJSON already understands Unicode and returns strings that have been decoded correctly.

Comment: but return incorrect unicode

Comment: Your code has errors and makes no sense. Please provide a compilable [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does it. If it returned correctly encoded text why would you need to decode UTF8. Surely you use the Unicode version of the library. Do you understand your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the source of lkJSON unit, there is an unnecessary Decode from UTF8 :

```
{$ifdef USE_D2009}
    js.FValue := UTF8ToString(ws);
{$else}
    js.FValue := UTF8Decode(ws);
{$endif}
```

If your JSON Strings are not encoded in UTF8, find and comment this lines and just assign ws value to the js.FValue :

```
    ...

    js := TlkJSONstring.Create;

//{$ifdef USE_D2009}
//    js.FValue := UTF8ToString(ws);
//{$else}
//    js.FValue := UTF8Decode(ws);
//{$endif}

    js.FValue := ws;

    ...
```

and there is no need to use AnsiToUtf8 or such methods, just use `getString` :

```
name := js.getString('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer does not work on Delphi 2010. If anyone else is still having or had this problem such as myself, simply find the function

```
function code2utf(iNumber: Integer): UTF8String;
```

and change the result to a simple chr

```
 result := chr(iNumber);
```